# Nginx in php: php files under in subdirectory thrown 404 error

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have starnge problem in my nginx server,php files under the subfolders thrown `404` error but the html files works fine.

**Folder structure**

```
html<folder>
  index.php

  test<folder>
         test.php //not working
         test.html //works fine
```

**Nginx configuration**

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /var/www/html;

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
           fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }


}ml
```

When access  `<ip-address>/test/test.html` works fine

When access  `<ip-address>/test/test.php` 404 error.

when access `<ip-address>` works fine(point to `html/index.php` file).

I've added the permissions in html folder,also enabled `cgi.fix_pathinfo=0` in php.ini file.

Comment: Possibly better suited for https://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html;
    autoindex on;

    location / {
    index index.php index.html;
    }

    location ~\.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the error from error.log   `"/var/www/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

Comment: can you tell me are you accessing `php` file or `html` file?

Comment: i am accessing php file

Comment: `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` and `index index.php index.html;`add this line in php block

Comment: You need to restart nginx after making this change. Can you confirm that you've done so?

Comment: restarted nginx after any changes but  it doesn't worked

Comment: Problem sloved ,actually its about php error reporting .the index.php file that i am try to load have a syntax error but the error reporting is disabled. now the error reporting is enabled